# how to keep the selected value in drop down?

Tags: jsp, jstl

this is my jsp code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Drop down</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        var d = [];
        $.each($("#delete option:selected"), function(){            
           d.push($(this).val());
        });
        var s=(d.join(", "));
        console.log(s);
       $("#delete_empId").val(s);
       console.log($("#delete_empId").val());

    });
});

</script>
</head>  
<body>   

  <div align="center">
    <form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteMultiple" modelAttribute="employee">  
    <table>  
    <tr>  
      <td>First Name :</td>  
      <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>  
     </tr>  
     <tr>  
      <td>Last Name :</td>  
      <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>  
     </tr> 
     <tr>  
      <td>emp_Id :</td>  
      <td><form:input path="emp_Id" /></td>  
     </tr> 
     <tr>
      <td>email_Id :</td>
      <td><form:input path="email_ID"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>phone_No :</td>
      <td><form:input path="phone_No"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>City :</td>
      <td><form:input path="city"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>  
      <td> </td>  
      <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>   
     </tr>  
    </table>  
  <input type= "hidden" id="delete_empId" name="delete_empId"   />

     </form:form>
</div>
  <div  align="center">  
  <h2 style="color:blue">SelectBox:</h2>
   <form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteMultipleEmpDetails" modelAttribute="employee">  
    <select  id="delete"  multiple name="employees">      
    <c:forEach items="${empList}" var="employee"> 
       <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${delete!=selected}">
           <option value= "${employee.emp_Id}" selected="selected"> ${employee.firstName} </option>
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
           <option value= "${employee.emp_Id}" >${employee.firstName}</option>
       </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
     ${msg} 
    </c:forEach>

    </select> 
     <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
    </form:form>
  </div>  
   <div>
         <h4 style="color:red">${message}</h4>  
    </div>
</body>  
</html>
```

My question is when i am selecting particular value in dropdown and search another value in search operation both values are getting selected.Please tell me the solution of when i click search button only the option of dropdown must be selected.Is my condition is correct.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what the workflow is? First the user searches, a bunch of employees is shown in the dropdown. Then the user selects some of them in the dropdown and clicks delete? Then what?